# Drivers to implement vGPU (GPU over IP)?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, gpu

Have two computers: one at home **(without GPU)** – and another **(with an nVidia CUDA GPU)** leased at a data center (cloud computing) or collecting dust at a friend’s home.

1. **Has anyone developed a driver** that lets my home computer harness the GPU of the remote computer over the Internet?

   Such a driver (let’s call it “vGPU”) would permit existing CUDA applications to use the remote GPU like a local GPU seamlessly (transparently – without modification).
2. Is there a fundamental reason **why it can’t exist?**
3. Are extant vGPU drivers (if any) scalable to handle **multiple GPU servers?**
4. **Latency** is not critical for my GPU applications (AI, crypto, 3D rendering, video processing) but it would be an added bonus if the latency of an extant solution were sufficient to permit real-time applications such as gaming.

I’d been looking for one for years before I ended up posting this question here.

Comment: “Has anyone developed a driver that lets my home computer harness the GPU of the remote computer over the Internet?” - Nvidia released an entire service based on this idea. However, it cannot be used for CUDA applications, at least currently.

Comment: http://www.nvidia.com/object/cloud-gaming.html

Comment: @Ramhound: I was vaguely aware of Nvidia’s GPU virtualisation technologies. It’s terrible that  none of this is available as an agnostic Windows driver for the benefit of CUDA applications.

Answer (score 1):

There is no GPU over IP driver that I know of.  However, if you have a whole physical computer at a data center you can use remote desktop.

Windows has Remote Desktop built-in, and a number of vnc remote software exist for linux.  You can connect to your computer over the internet, and install your software and run the software on the remote computer with the GPU.

However, what you can't do is directly add the GPU's computing power to your PC.  The bandwidth requirements are just to great.  The pci-e 1.0 x16 slots have 4GB/s and 2.0 is 8GB/s bandwidth, and this is especially hard for gaming.  You can steam 1080p video over the internet of what is going on, but you will need fast internet speeds or it will lag.

OpenCL or CUDA maybe be able to use a lower bandwidth level, as the GPU could spend a long time on each computation and spend less communicating.

However, because the GPU has to be plugged into a computer to be useful, then you might as well run your software completely on the remote computer.

Comment: Existence of such solutions as [rCUDA](http://www.rcuda.net/index.php/what-s-rcuda.html), [Nvidia vGPU](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/design-visualization/technologies/virtual-gpu/), [SETI@home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SETI@home), the [“remote solution”](http://ccwu.me/vsfm/doc.html#cpu_replacements) for VisualSFM, as well as other distributed computing platforms, contradicts your claim that GPU has to be plugged into a computer in order to be useful. Do I misunderstand these applications?

Comment: @7vujy0f0hy  SETI@home is exactly like I said.  It downloads a unit of work to your PC which has their software running on it.  The SETI@home back end only sends out work units collects the results.

Comment: SETI@home doesn’t run the entire task on the server, only small quanta of the task. How is that fundamentally different from my ideal vGPU driver? (Other than for it being a single-purpose solution.) One important property of *not* running an entire task on a leased machine is data security. Also existence of rCUDA and Nvidia vGPU appears to contradict your belief even more directly. In any case, +1 goes to you for attempt and effort.

Comment: NVIDIA vGPU:"NVIDIA GPUs across virtual machines (VMs) and virtual applications"  So if you have a vmware server you can allow all of them to share the GPU.  In a VM the entire software package runs on the remote PC, and you only connect to it via a protocol similar to remote desktop.
My understanding is you want to send out the packets in real-time streaming GPU to be processed by the GPU and the results to immediately return to you.  If you want to packetize your work, and connect to a remote server, and have the results eventually come back, you can do it but it will be a lot of work.